# Error: "No cached version available for offline mode"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-2.3

How to clear this error?

Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download jackson-annotations.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.2): No cached version available for offline mode
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable the "Offline Work" under Gradle section from settings.

[image]